# LARAVEL 5.6: catching exception inside a job class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to catch an exception inside a job but it seems the try/catch bock has no effect.

```
    /**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $progress=0;
    $step=100/count($this->itemsId);

    event(new JobProgressUpdate($progress, '', true, $this->broadcastChannel));
    foreach ($this->itemsId as $itemId) {
        $message='ITEM '.$itemId.': ';
        $success=true;
        try{
            $this->meliCredential->setItemStatus($itemId,$this->status);
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $message+=$e->getMessage();
            $success=false;
        }

        $progress+=$step;
        event(new JobProgressUpdate($progress, $message, $success, $this->broadcastChannel));
    }
}
```

The idea is to avoid the job to be marked as failed and just send a message of the exception to the client.

so the question is, How to catch exceptions inside a job handler???

I don't want to stop the execution, that's why i need to catch the exception.

Comment: It probably means the exception is thrown outside of your try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

it was just dumb question.
The problem was initially namespace issue of the Exception class (initially i was not using the "\"). 
After that the job crashed with the line  `$message+=$e->getMessage();`
This was replaced for `$message=$message.$e->getMessage();` and now its working fine.